# Android new accounttype without AuthenticatorActivity

Tags: android, account, accountmanager

I'm writing an app which should use an own account for contacts.
I found a lot of examples in the internet but not that what I want.
And the SampleSyncAdapter from the samples doesn't help me so much.

What I want is a something like

```
    AccountManager _accountMgr = AccountManager.get(context);
    Account [] accounts = _accountMgr.getAccounts();
    final Account account = new Account(accounts[0].name, "com.myapplication");
    mAccountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, null, null);
```

What I don't want is a new account with auhtentication where I have to input a username and a password.

The issue is, that my app reads the contacts and in the moment I'm using a sqllite database where I store
the contactid and further information to this ID which my app needs and which I can't store in the normal contacts.
Normally no problem. But what happened if someone needs a new smartphone. Contacts you can export and import in your new phone.
But during the import the contactid could change. Then my app can't link the contactid which I stored in my SQLLite-database to the
right contact in the new smartphone.
My idea was, to create an new account for my app (like "WhatsApp" is doing that) and storing there my additonal contactinformation.
This account I can export and import it to a new smartphone.

That's right, or? But for that I don't need an AuthenticatorActivity with username and password and no authentication.
I only need a new account. :-)

How can I solve that? Does someone has an example for me?
Thanks for any help

Best regards
Tom